# Как вытащить из данной строки значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Я делаю парсер дискорда, и я остановился на том что в цикле получаю такую строку:

```
[<Attachment id=794604792886198302 filename='25_3.jpg' url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/794541373440524328/794604792886198302/25_3.jpg'>]
```

Так вот: Как мне получить значение url, из этого списка? Может каждый раз проходиться по строке, и искать префикс url=', и возвращать на выходе значение после префикса, с концом '? Тогда как это сделать?
Код парсера:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.channel.id) # Debug
    message_history = await message.channel.history(limit=10000).flatten()
    for message_ in message_history:
        if message_.attachments != []:
            string = message_.attachments
            print(string)
```

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код парсера, где получаете эту "строку"?

Answer (score 0):

Я сам решил проблему. Пишу ибо может кому-то понадобится. Поскольку эта "строка" была списком, надо было написать вместо

```
string = message_.attachments
```

Вот это:

```
string = message_.attachments[0].url
```

Comment: Для того примера "строки", который в вопросе, это не будет работать, потому что там невалидные данные.

Comment: Ну хз, у меня сработало именно с этой.